# Use a style for react.js map without using CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

So I have this css code:

```
.tab-top {
    padding-left: 12%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    color: var(--cloudy-white);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-family: "NTR Regular";
    font-size: 15px;

}

.tab-top > div {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 3%;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

How would I do this in react.js with the following code:

```
function Navigation() {
  const topTabs = tabs.map(tab =>
      <div>
        {tab}
      </div>
    );
  return (
    <div className="tab-top">
      {topTabs}
    </div>
  );
}
```

(tabs is declared)

Also I'm fairly new to react.js so if I can improve the following code in any way please leave suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use style of react if you want create mutiple css style do like this**

```
function Navigation() {
const styles={ tabtop:{
    textAlign: "center",
    marginLeft: "2%",
    marginTop: "1%",
},
anohter:{ width:"100%"},
}

  const topTabs = tabs.map(tab =>
      <div>
        {tab}
      </div>
    );
  return (
    <div style={styles.tabtop}>
      {topTabs}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**or you can do it like that for single usage**

```
function Navigation() {
  const topTabs = tabs.map(tab =>
      <div>
        {tab}
      </div>
    );
  return (
    <div style={{
    textAlign: "center",
    marginLeft: "2%",
    marginTop: "1%",
}}>
      {topTabs}
    </div>
  );
}
```

or
**i think it should be like this**

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
const Thing = styled.div.attrs(() => ({ tabIndex: 0 }))`
.tab-top {
    padding-left: 12%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    color: var(--cloudy-white);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-family: "NTR Regular";
    font-size: 15px;

}

.tab-top > div {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 3%;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
  `;
function Navigation() {
  const topTabs = tabs.map(tab =>
      <div>
        {tab}
      </div>
    );
  return (
    <Thing className="tab-top">
      {topTabs}
    </Thing>
  );
}
```

Comment: I edited my original post. Is there no way to implement the "<" part in react.js*?

Comment: in same component folder you have to create file css and put you're css like usual and import it in react and it will work otherwise you can use styled coponent  https://javascript.plainenglish.io/react-styled-components-more-complex-selectors-and-selectively-passing-props-9e12a3d60167  @walid